# PostgreSQL display month in correct order

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to display data from a table sorted on the month in 'Jan', 'Feb' format. If I use to_char function, the sorting won't be correct. How can this be done? Sample data and query I am trying.

```
SELECT * FROM tb;

     dt     
------------
 2014-12-12    
 2014-01-01


SELECT to_char(dt,'Mon') FROM tb ORDER BY to_char(dt,'Mon');

 to_char 
---------
 Dec   
 Jan
```

Comment: Using `ORDER BY to_char(dt,'Mon')` is going to give you the alphabetical ordering by the stringified month name (Apr, Aug, Dec, Feb, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to order by date and display month as per the date. Try something like:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(dt,'Mon') 
FROM tb 
ORDER BY dt
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I couldn't order by dt because I had an error

> ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list.

I did the following:

```
SELECT mon
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT DATE_PART('MONTH', dt) AS m, TO_CHAR(dt,'Mon') AS mon FROM tb) AS mname
ORDER BY m;
```

I used DISTINCT to avoid repeated months.